# Reuse of function signature, type hints and intellisense *args **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typing

I was writing some python and got stumbled by an issue. I have tried to search for answers but seem to be lacking good keywords to find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to reuse a function signature form another function. The end goal is to have intellisense and low maintenance of the wrapper.

```py
class B:
    """ Forigin class from other package """
    def __enter__(self):
        ...
    def __exti__(self, *_):
        ...
    def send(self, msg, timeout, ...):  # The function signature I want to re use for my function func. 
        ...
    def get(self):
        ...

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.other = B()  # I don't control this class

    def func(self, *args, **kwargs):  # <- I want to make MyPy and Intellisense to show hits from the B.send method. 
        with self.other as connection:
            connection.send(*args, **kwargs)  # fire and forget method
            response = connection.get()  # get data from a buffer (takes no arguments)
        return response
```

Is there a way to use the function signature from `self.other.send` as the function signature for `A.func`?

Searching for something like `functools.Wraps` but for this usage.

I've tried using `functools.Wraps`, looking into `ParamSpec`. Oh man typing takes a while to get into.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No. The function signature isn't data, it's syntax. `ParamSpec` is used for capturing the *types* in order to transfer them into another type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by creating a no-op decorator factory. The construct looks like this:

```py
import typing as t

P = t.ParamSpec("P")
R = t.TypeVar("R")

def withSignatureFrom(
    f: t.Callable[t.Concatenate[t.Any, P], R], /
) -> t.Callable[
    [t.Callable[t.Concatenate[t.Any, P], R]], t.Callable[t.Concatenate[t.Any, P], R]
]:
    return lambda _: _
```

- `f: t.Callable[t.Concatenate[t.Any, P], R]` indicates the signature to use;
- `-> t.Callable ...` is the decorator returned by the decorator factory. At runtime, this is the no-op `lambda _: _` (a decorator which just returns the decorated object unchanged).

`Concatenate[t.Any, P]` is to prevent type mismatches in the first (`self`) parameter, because in your case, you're using an instance method signature from `class B` on `class A`, which are unrelated. To clarify, if you wanted exact typing, the decorator factory may look like this instead:

```py
def withSignatureFrom(
    f: t.Callable[t.Concatenate["B", P], R], /
) -> t.Callable[
    [t.Callable[t.Concatenate["A", P], R]], t.Callable[t.Concatenate["A", P], R]
]:
    return lambda _: _
```

But exact typing of the instance parameter is rarely useful (and if you do this, you can't use this construct outside of the classes `B` and `A`).

---

Complete minimal working example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t
import typing_extensions as tx

def withSignatureFrom(
    f: t.Callable[t.Concatenate[t.Any, P], R], /
) -> t.Callable[
    [t.Callable[t.Concatenate[t.Any, P], R]], t.Callable[t.Concatenate[t.Any, P], R]
]:
    return lambda _: _

class B:
    """Foreign class from other package"""
    def __enter__(self) -> tx.Self: ...
    def __exit__(self, *_: t.Any) -> None: ...
    def send(self, msg, timeout): ...
    def get(self): ...

class A:
    other: B

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.other = B()  # I don't control this class

    @withSignatureFrom(B.send)
    def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with self.other as connection:
            connection.send(*args, **kwargs)  # fire and forget method
            response = connection.get()  # get data from a buffer (takes no arguments)
        return response
```

```
>>> # mypy(error): Missing positional arguments "msg", "timeout" in call to "func" of "A"  [call-arg]
>>> # Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues): Arguments missing for parameters "msg", "timeout"
>>> A().func()
```