How to copy method type hint with decorator in Python?
I want to use a decorator, that copies method signature into another class method like this:
class A:
    def func_source(self, x: str, y: int = 0) -> None: ...
    
class B:
    @copy_method_signature(A.func_source)
    def func_target(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int: ...

expecting B.func_target to show the same type hint as A.func_source except for self and return types (checking with Pyright, namely VSCode Pylance with all recommended Python extensions installed)
B.func_target(...)  # (self: B, x: str, y: int = 0) -> int

b = B()
b.func_target(...)  # (x: str, y: int = 0) -> int


Implementation with typing.Concatenate
Borrowed this decorator mainly from python/typing GitHub Issues: 'Proposal: signature copying for kwargs':
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Callable
from functools       import wraps
from typing          import Any, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

SP = ParamSpec("SP")  # Source Parameters
TR = TypeVar("TR")    # Target Return
TS = TypeVar("TS")    # Target Self

def copy_method_signature(source: Callable[Concatenate[Any, SP], Any]):
    def wrapper(target: Callable[Concatenate[TS, ...], TR]) -> Callable[Concatenate[TS, SP], TR]:
        @wraps(source)
        def wrapped(self: TS, *args: SP.args, **kwargs: SP.kwargs) -> TR:
            return target(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

Two major things I've changed are:

func_target doesn't copy func_source return type unlike it was originally implemented - it remains int instead of func_source's None (passed in TR)
func_target shows its self argument type correctly - it remains B instead of just Any from original implementation (passed in TS)

The problems are:

B.func_target() is expected to hint (self: B, x: str, y: int = 0) -> int,
but hints  with the first argument missing its name
b.func_target() is expected to highlight x: str as the first argument, but highlights y: int = 0 


Implementation with Callback typing.Protocol
A part of these problems is mentioned above in the same thread with a possible solution proposed next reply - defining callable type using a Callback typing.Protocol instead of typing.Callable[...] syntax with typing.Concatenate should preserve B.target_func's self argument name and type.
That's the solution I've come up with:
...  # all imports from above
from typing import Protocol

# pylint: disable = no-self-argument, typevar-name-incorrect-variance

SP = ParamSpec("SP")                    # Source Parameters
TR = TypeVar("TR", covariant=True)      # Target Return
TS = TypeVar("TS", contravariant=True)  # Target Self

class SourceMethod(Protocol[SP, TR, TS]):
    def __call__(_, self: TS, *args: SP.args, **kwargs: SP.kwargs) -> TR: ...
class TargetMethod(Protocol[TR, TS]):
    def __call__(_, self: TS, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> TR: ...

def copy_method_signature(source: SourceMethod[SP, Any, Any]):
    def wrapper(target: TargetMethod[TR, TS]) -> SourceMethod[SP, TR, TS]:
        @wraps(source)
        def wrapped(self: TS, *args: SP.args, **kwargs: SP.kwargs) -> TR:
            return target(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

Technically speaking, there is no need to replace every Callable[Concatenate[...], ...], the only place where it seems to be crucial is
...
    def wrapper(target: TargetMethod[TR, TS]) -> SourceMethod[SP, TR, TS]:
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...                                                     this one  

Result are the following:

B.func_target() works as expected - 
b.func_target() is expected to hint (x: str, y: int = 0) -> int, but hints 


No further attempts to fix these problems resulted in any progress, I'm genuinely stuck at that point
P.S.
By the way, @copy_callable_signature decorator from the first link works perfectly well on both plain functions copying signature from another plain function and methods copying from methods of the same class. Here it is just in case:
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Callable
from functools       import wraps
from typing          import Any, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

SP = ParamSpec("SP")  # Source Parameters
TR = TypeVar("TR")    # Target Return

def copy_callable_signature(source: Callable[SP, Any]):
    def wrapper(target: Callable[..., TR]) -> Callable[SP, TR]:
        @wraps(source)
        def wrapped(*args: SP.args, **kwargs: SP.kwargs) -> TR:
            return target(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper


UPD:
Adapted Code on Pyright Playground for @blhsing answer - basically all the same problems but in shorter implementation
(couldn't add as a comment - link's too long)

Found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304643/reuse-of-function-signature-type-hints-and-intellisense-args-kwargs, seems relatable. Leaving it here for now just not to lose it

You can adapt the decorator factory from this answer to copy type hints of parameters from another method while using Concatenate to preserve the type of self and the returning type of the target method:
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, Concatenate, Any

SP = ParamSpec('SP')
TR = TypeVar('TR')
TS = TypeVar('TS')

def copy_method_signature(
    f: Callable[Concatenate[Any, SP], Any]
) -> Callable[
    [Callable[Concatenate[TS, ...], TR]], Callable[Concatenate[TS, SP], TR]
]:
    return lambda _: _  # type: ignore[return-value]

class A:
    def func_source(self, x: str, y: int = 0) -> None:
        ...

class B:
    @copy_method_signature(A.func_source)
    def func_target(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        ...

Demo with Pyright here

Added an update at the bottom with a link to adapted code. Basically, it's all the same problems, but with an easier implementation - that's progress anyway in my opinion
